# Pass context to a controller from the view in Ember

Tags: ember.js

Template controlled by someParentController

```
{{#each post in content}}
{{view App.PostView postBinding="post"}}
{{/each}}
```

Setting an instance of the controller on the view

```
App.PostView = Ember.View.extend
  post: null # set when the view is created
  controller: App.PostController.create()
  templateName: 'post.handlebars'
```

Now my view instance has the context instead of my controller instance. Is there a cleverer way to handle this? I would use an {{outlet}} if I was routing to a particular post, but the main template is displaying all posts. I want each to post to have its own controller though. It doesn't seem right to create an outlet for every post since you cannot namespace a dynamic number of outlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass the view entirely by using the following syntax on your action helpers in post.handlebars.

```
{{action someMethodOnController context="post" target="controller"}}
```

Comment: This works for `action` events and for my particular circumstance, but I guess the question still stands, how can a controller set its context from its view automatically?

Comment: Can I pass the entire view instance to the controller like this:           this.get("controller").addRecord(this);